# New key/value in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have a simple question that I'm not able to find the answer to.

Can I add a new key/value to my userdefault just by

```
[userdefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"onSwitch"]
```

Or must it be in the defaults.plist first?

Comment: NSUserDefaults != property lists

Comment: Yes I tried it and I have problems with it. That's why I asked here.
I have used userdefaults for a long time without problems and now it's suddenly a problem.

Comment: You should probably describe the problem you're having then, so people can help you figure it out.

Comment: Well I couldn't formulate a question because it is quite straight forward.
I found an error where I had stored a value that confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add a new key/value to your user-defaults.

If it exists it will overwrite it, otherwise a new key/value pair will be created.

Answer (score 0):

If the value doesn't exist already it will create it and set it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. :)

Make sure to add this code when you add any key/value in user defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: No, please don't. -synchronize is slow, and is *not* necessary under normal conditions. On OSX it's almost never necessary, and on iOS it's only necessary when you're about to terminate.

Comment: You do not need to call `synchronize` after adding a value. The only time you need to call `synchronize` is if there is a chance the app will be terminated before the user defaults are automatically synchronized.